Addon works from Text Editor, but fails to enable from Add-ons preferences
I've written very simple addon that exports triangulated and quad mesh of selected object, deleting all material slots and applying transformation. And all work fine if I run it from the Text Editor, but after installing it as an add-on, it gives me an error after trying to enable it.
Here's the code:
import bpy
import os
import struct
from bpy.props import StringProperty, BoolProperty
from bpy.types import Operator
from bpy.utils import register_class, unregister_class

basedir = os.path.dirname(bpy.data.filepath)
selection = bpy.context.selected_objects

view_layer = bpy.context.view_layer

obj_active = view_layer.objects.active
selection = bpy.context.selected_objects

path = "C:/"

def main(context):
    global path

    for obj in selection:
        obj.data.materials.clear()
        bpy.ops.object.transform_apply(location=True, rotation=True, scale=True)
        bpy.ops.object.modifier_add(type='TRIANGULATE')
        bpy.context.object.modifiers["Triangulate"].keep_custom_normals = True
        obj.select_set(True)
        # some exporters only use the active object
        view_layer.objects.active = obj
        name = bpy.path.clean_name(obj.name)
        fn = os.path.join(basedir, name)
        bpy.ops.export_scene.fbx(filepath=path + name + ".fbx", use_selection=True)
        bpy.ops.object.modifier_remove(modifier="Triangulate")
        print("Triangulated mesh has been written:", fn)
        bpy.ops.export_scene.fbx(filepath=path + name + "_quad.fbx", use_selection=True)
        print("Quad mesh has been written:", fn)
        obj.select_set(False)
        view_layer.objects.active = obj_active

for obj in selection:
    obj.select_set(True)
    
class SaveTrisAndQuad(bpy.types.Operator):
    """Export quad and triangulated meshes, apply transforms and delete materials"""
    bl_idname = "object.savetrisandquad"
    bl_label = "Save tiangulated and Quad mesh"
    dirpath = bpy.props.StringProperty(subtype='DIR_PATH') 

    def execute(self, context):
        main(context)
        return {'FINISHED'}

class SelectDirExample(bpy.types.Operator):
    """Select output directory"""
    bl_idname = "object.selectdir"
    bl_label = "Select Dir"
    bl_options = {'REGISTER'}
    global path

    directory: StringProperty(
        name="dirpath",
        description="Where I will save my stuff",
        subtype='DIR_PATH'
        )

    filter_folder: BoolProperty(
        default=True,
        options={"HIDDEN"}
        )

    def execute(self, context):
        global path
        print("Selected dir: '" + self.directory + "'")
        path =  self.directory
        context.area.tag_redraw()
        return {'FINISHED'}

    def invoke(self, context, event):
        context.window_manager.fileselect_add(self)
        # Tells Blender to hang on for the slow user input
        return {'RUNNING_MODAL'}
    
class RedNeckPanel(bpy.types.Panel):
    bl_label = "RedNeck Tools"
    bl_idname = "OBJECT_PT_redneck"
    bl_space_type = 'VIEW_3D'
    bl_region_type = 'UI'
    bl_category = "RedNeck"
    global path

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        obj = context.object
        layout.label(text="FBX Mesh Exporter")
        row = layout.row()
        row.scale_y = 3.0        
        row.operator(SelectDirExample.bl_idname, text="Select Directory", icon='FILE_FOLDER')
        row = layout.row()
        row.scale_y = 3.0  
        row.operator(SaveTrisAndQuad.bl_idname, text="Export Mesh", icon='EXPORT')
        layout.label(text="Output Directory: " + "<" + path + ">")
        row = layout.row()        
    

_classes = [
    SaveTrisAndQuad,
    RedNeckPanel,
    SelectDirExample
]

def register():
    for cls in _classes:
        register_class(cls)
        SelectDirExample
    
def unregister():
    for cls in _classes:
        unregister_class(cls)
        SelectDirExample  
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()

And here's what I get if I trying to enable the add-on:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 4.1\4.1\scripts\modules\addon_utils.py", line 376, in enable
    mod = importlib.import_module(module_name)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 4.1\4.1\python\Lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1204, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1176, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1147, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 690, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 940, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\okato\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\4.1\scripts\addons\RedNeckTools.py", line 22, in <module>
    basedir = os.path.dirname(bpy.data.filepath)
                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: '_RestrictData' object has no attribute 'filepath'

Any suggestions why this may happens and how to fix it?

You have wrong indentation in many places for one. Global variable might not be a good idea. Try fixing those see how it goes. Add-on bl_info info is missing, see examples in the Text Editor's Templates menu.

I don't think this is a good question for BSE. The script is a mess with many issues, it would be just rewriting it, not giving an answer to a question. I think you should attempt to fix it yourself and then if you face difficulties ask about specific issues one at a time. Maybe start with a working example from Text Editor's menu and test it every step as you modify it.

When you run a script in a text editor, you can access bpy.data. in the register function at that time.
But in the add-on, when you open blender, the register() function runs very early and you don't have access to bpy.data., bpy.context., bpy.ops. and get a _RestrictData error.
To fix that you can:
1.  Late Register
import bpy

def register():
    bpy.app.timers.register(late_register)

def late_register():
    ob = bpy.context.object
    ..

Or
2. bpy.app.handlers.
This method does not work when you re-enable the add-on
def register():
    bpy.app.handlers.load_post.append(late_register)

def late_register(dummy):
   ob = bpy.context.object
   ..

